# Label and Image in TableViewCell are disappearing after scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my iOS App I've already created tables and much other stuff but now, while implementing a list of "Reviews" a label and the image in the "reviewCell" are disappearing after scrolling down and up again and I can't figure out why! 
I already debugged the code but everything is set correctly.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reviewCell", for: indexPath) as! ReviewCell
    let review = self.reviews[indexPath.row]

    if review.authorName == nil{
        self.reviews[indexPath.row].authorName = NSLocalizedString("ANONYMOUS", comment: "")
        cell.authorLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("ANONYMOUS", comment: "")
    }
    else{
        cell.authorLabel.text = review.authorName
    }
    cell.ratingView.rating = Double(review.rating)
    cell.reviewTextLabel.text = review.text
    if(self.reviewProfileImages[indexPath.row] == nil){
        cell.profileImage.image = UIImage()
        downloadImageAndSaveForKey(key: indexPath.row, url: review.profile_photo_url);
    }
    else{
        cell.profileImage.image = self.reviewProfileImages[indexPath.row]!;
    }

    return cell
}
```

ReviewCell:

```
class ReviewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingView: CosmosView!
    @IBOutlet weak var reviewTextLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

The images are saved in a Map [Int:UIImage] to prevent downloading the image each time.

Without Scrolling (On Simulator, the images and the author label is loading displayed for only few ms):

[image]

Storyboard:

[image]

## edit

DownloadImageAndSaveForKey function

```
func downloadImageAndSaveForKey(key: Int, url: String){
        let catPictureURL = URL(string: url)!
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: catPictureURL) { (data, response, error) in
            if let e = error {
                print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
            } else {
                if (response as? HTTPURLResponse) != nil {
                    if let imageData = data {
                        self.reviewProfileImages[key] = UIImage(data: imageData)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
                }
            }
        }
        downloadPicTask.resume()
    }
```

## edit2

Print Row 0 (everything displayed correctly): `Row 0, authorLabelText: Optional("Anonymous"), profile image Optional(<UIImage: 0x1d40bc380>, {128, 128})`

Print Row 0 (after scrolling, disappeared): `Row 0, authorLabelText: Optional("Anonymous"), profile image Optional(<UIImage: 0x1d40bc380>, {128, 128})`

Comment: What does 'downloadImageAndSaveForKey' method do? It looks like title and image are set to nil or empty string/image.

Also please remove `cell.profileImage.image = UIImage()` since setting profile image to empty UIImage does nothing, just set it to nil

Comment: If I understand correctly, profileImage & authorLabel are disappearing. It's only happening when you're checking whether they're nil or not. Perhaps, try removing the if.. else and check if you're getting the desired scroll performance.

Comment: @Ladislav edited above

Comment: What I would do is before `return cell` I would add some logging info like 
`print("Row \(row), authorLabelText: \(cell.authorLabel.text), profile image \(cell.profileImage.image)")` Then see what gets logged when images and title disappears.

Comment: Also I would advise agains doing `tableView.reloadData()` when you get image, since you know cells indexPath just reload that cell when done or better yet just get the cell and update it's `profileImage`'s image

Comment: edited the print above

Comment: All seems fine from logs...I would then add more logs, frame of both `cell.profileImage` and `cell.authorLabel`, alpha of both and if they are hidden or not...

Comment: *"a label and the image ... are disappearing after scrolling"*. Step 1, use Debug View Hierarchy to see if the objects are still there but somehow hidden or out-of-frame. Step 2, give the imageView and label background colors in the prototype, so you can visually see if they are "missing" or just empty". Step 3, comment-out the entire `if / else` block for the Profile Images in `cellForRowAt` and see if the Label continues to disappear.